# Writing a generic with chaining instead of columns of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics, kendo-grid

I have some columns in my script like following :

```
  <script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
              height: 400,
              columns: [
                 "ProductName", 
                 { field: "UnitPrice", format: "{0:c}", width: "150px" },
                 { field: "UnitsInStock", width: "150px" },
                 { field: "Discontinued", width: "100px" },
                 { command: "destroy", title: "Delete", width: "110px" }
              ]
  });
  </script>
```

I want to write extension method using generic and chaining I need something like this in c# :

```
   <% Page.Grid<Product>()
     .Columns.Add(c=> {
       c.add("ProductName").Title("Product Name");
       c.add("UnitPrice").Title("Unit Price").Width("150px");
     }).Render(); %>
```

how I can write c# method extension for it I need to use this method in asp.net form.

Comment: It's a little difficult to answer this without knowing what `Columns.Add()` expects.

Comment: you know I need sth as a wrapper like asp.net-mvc but in asp.net form. it is kendo ui grid but it javascript open source. it must convert to javascript or string.

Comment: @Matthew Watson. Sorry I've edit my post now and I think it is more clear.

Comment: Well I now know I have no hope of answering this - but hopefully with the extra information someone else will!

Comment: Thanks for your truthfully! but I need it because I don't want to buy mvc wrapper I need my own tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out my own answer:

```
Kend._2013.Extension.KendoGrid<string>.Name("KendoGrid1")
                                          .Columns(c => new Kend._2013.Extension.Column[]
                                          {                                                                                   
                                                c.Add("ProductID").Title("ID").Width(100),
                                                c.Add("ProductName").Title("Name").Width(150),
                                                c.Add("UnitPrice").Title("Price").Width(150),
                                                c.Add("Discontinued").Title("Amount").Width(150),
                                                c.Add("UnitsInStock").Title("Units In").Width(150),                                           
                                          });





    namespace Kend._2013.Extension
{
    public class Column
    {
        private string fieldName;
        private string title;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        private readonly Column previous;
    private Column(Column previous)
    {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public Column Add(string name)
    {
        this.fieldName = name;
        return new Column(this);
    }

    public Column Title(string t)
    {
        this.title = t;
        return new Column(this);
    }

    public Column Width(int w)
    {
        this.width = w;
        return new Column(this);
    }

    public Column Height(int h)
    {
        this.height = h;
        return new Column(this);
    }
}

public class KendoGridDataSource
{
}

public class KendoGrid<T>
{
    private readonly T target;
    private readonly KendoGrid<T> previous;

    private KendoGrid(T target, KendoGrid<T> previous)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public static KendoGrid<T> Name(T target)
    {
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, null);
    }

    private bool isFitInPage;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Column columns;
    private bool pageable;
    private bool sortable;
    private bool filterable;
    private bool editable;
    private string uICulture;
    private bool showContextMenu;
    private bool showFilterMenu;
    private bool showGroupArea;
    private bool showToolbars;
    private KendoGridDataSource DataSource;
    private bool DataBatching;

    private void FitToPage(bool b)
    {
        this.isFitInPage = b;
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Height(int h)
    {
        this.height = h;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Width(int w)
    {
        this.width = w;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Pageable(bool pageable)
    {
        this.pageable = pageable;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Sortable(bool sortable)
    {
        this.sortable = sortable;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Filterable(bool filterable)
    {
        this.filterable = filterable;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> Editable(bool editable)
    {
        this.editable = editable;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> ShowContextMenu(bool show)
    {
        this.showContextMenu = show;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> ShowFilterMenu(bool show)
    {
        this.showFilterMenu = show;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> ShowGroupArea(bool show)
    {
        this.showGroupArea = show;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public KendoGrid<T> ShowToolbars(bool show)
    {
        this.showToolbars = show;
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }

    public KendoGrid<T> Columns(Expression<Func<Column, Column>> col)
    {           
        var a = col.Compile();
        Column c = new Column();
        a(c);
        return new KendoGrid<T>(target, this);
    }
    public void Render(){ // write html }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this something that KendoGrid already has or did you find a third-party/open source extension?

Comment: It is open source script and I've written a wrapper extension for it to provide more reuse-ability and working at server-side it work both asp.net-form and mvc and also it is free I don't have to pay it when I've written it, In fact it is not complete but the way authoring is the same.